# What does 'significant calls' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean ***important and crucial calls*** or ***considerable calls***?

> By 2050, the global population is expected to rise to nine billion and
> there have been ***significant calls*** for a change in the way the
> world is dealing with growing water shortages. The approaching water
> crisis will threaten half of humanity by 2030. Our ever-increasing
> population is stretching our ability to provide clean water for our
> needs, from agriculture and manufacturing to the most basic one of
> all: drinking water.

[How Emerging Technologies and Biomimicry can Help Solving Water Problems: Desert case Studies](https://www.omicsonline.org/open-access/how-emerging-technologies-and-biomimicry-can-help-solving-waterproblems-desert-case-studies-2329-8863-1000e130.php?aid=61694)

Comment: You're assuming it doesn't mean those things and more, like the calls have been important and considerable, as well as relatively large in quantity, meaningful, and systematically caused. Sometimes, a person chooses a word and remains ambiguous about what of its definitions is meant in order to aptly and succinctly convey that more than one or even all of its definitions apply, which appears to be the case here, essentially a double-entendre gone quintuple-entendre.

Comment: Which meaning of [crucial](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crucial) are you thinking of? It can mean different things. These phrases are all a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

One of the definitions of “call” is that it can be a request or demand. That is the definition in use here.

Significant means “meaningful” or “substantial,” as always.